Can't fetch the images from the public folder although the other details in the page is working perfectly
The images are not fetched and is showing internal server error
The Clerk authentication is throwing the following error as :
⨯ Error: Clerk: auth() was called but Clerk can't detect usage of authMiddleware(). Please ensure the following:

authMiddleware() is used in your Next.js Middleware.
Your Middleware matcher is configured to match this route or page.
If you are using the src directory, make sure the Middleware file is inside of it.

But I have verified that i follow all these steps and now my authentication is defining a anonymous member at this particular route which makes it unable to fetch the image.
I wanted the images to be shown without any error and also not throw any authentication error in the following routes.

show code for us to understand the issue

I will show a standard solution NextJs/Clerk code you can follow to fix the error: (Failed to load ressource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)) :
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { authMiddleware } from 'clerk';

const SomePage = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchImages = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/images', {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            // here you must include Clerk authentication token (if available)
            Authorization: `Bearer ${YOUR_CLERK_TOKEN}`,
          },
        });
        if (response.ok) {
          const data = await response.json();
          setImages(data.images);
        } else {
          console.error('Failed to fetch images:', response.statusText);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching images:', error);
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchImages();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {loading ? (
        <p>Loading images...</p>
      ) : (
        <div>
          {images.map((image) => (
            <img key={image.id} src={image.url} alt={image.alt} />
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export const getServerSideProps = async ({ req, res }) => {
  // add Clerk authMiddleware to authenticate requests here
  await authMiddleware(req, res);

  return {
    props: {},
  };
};

export default SomePage;

